# Replace tabs with spaces

Tags: c, formatting, io

I wrote a program that replaces tabs with spaces. First, I defined a maximum length of an input string in the constant `MAX_LIMIT`. Next, I declared the procedure `detab` that takes two arguments: an input string and a maximum length. In the procedure I read characters until encountering EOF. I'm replacing tabs with four spaces and I'm checking if `index` is equal to `limit`, and if yes, then I break the loop. Finally, I created a `str` character array. I called on it the `detab` procedure and I printed out the value of `str` in `main`.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_LIMIT 1000

void detab(char str[], int limit);

int main(void) {
    char str[MAX_LIMIT];
    detab(str, MAX_LIMIT);
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}

void detab(char str[], int limit) {
    char current;
    int index = 0;
    int stop = 0;
    while ((current = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (stop) {
            break;
        }
        if (current == '\t') {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4 && !stop; i++) {
                if (index == limit) {
                    stop = 1;
                } else {
                    str[index++] = ' ';
                }
            }
        } else {
            str[index++] = current;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I improve this program? Is it an optimal solution of this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [K&R 1-20 Converting tabs to spaces using idiomatic C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31712/kr-1-20-converting-tabs-to-spaces-using-idiomatic-c)

Comment: @tinstaafl A question is not a duplicate here if it solves the same problem as code in some other question. And the code seems sufficiently different not to be a direct copy.

Answer (score 3):

- First of all, it is not exactly doing what is expected of `detab`. The visual appearance of the detabbed text shall remain the same. You need to insert as many spaces as required to reach the *next tab stop*, not necessarily 4 of them.

  For example, a string `ab\tc` should become

  ```
  ab  c
  ```

  (2 spaces inserted) whereas your code produces

  ```
  ab    c
  ```
- `detab` does not zero-terminate the string. It is an (un)lucky coincidence that the code produces meaningful output.
- The limit condition is only tested during the tab expansion. A long sequence of ordinary characters will overrun the buffer.